# Django: Combine a date and time field and filter

Tags: django, django-filter

I have a django model that has a date field and a separate time field. I am trying to use a filter to find a value on the latest record by date/time that is less than the current record's date time.

How do I use annotate/aggregate to combine the date and time fields into one and then do a filter on it?

```
models.py
class Note(models.model):
    note_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    note_time = models.TimeField(null=True)
    note_value = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)

def get_last(n):
    """
        n: Note
        return: Return the note_value of the most recent Note prior to given Note.
    """
    latest = Note.objects.filter(
        note_date__lte=n.note_date
    ).order_by(
        '-note_date', '-note_time'
    ).first()

    return latest.note_value if latest else return 0
```

This will return any notes from a previous date, but if I have a two notes on the same date, one at 3pm and one at 1pm, and I send the 3pm note to the function, I want to get the value of the 1pm note. Is there a way to annotate the two fields into one for comparison, or do I have to perform a raw SQL query? Is there a way to convert the date and time component into one, similar to how you could use `Concat` for strings?

```
Note.objects.annotate(
    my_dt=Concat('note_date', 'note_time')
).filter(
    my_dt__lt=Concat(models.F('note_date'), models.F('note_time')
).first()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer using `models.Q` here: [filter combined date and time in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161042/filter-combined-date-and-time-in-django)

```
Note.objects.filter(
    models.Q(note_date__lt=n.note_date) | models.Q(
        note_date=n.note_date,
        note_time__lt=n.note_time
    )
).first()
```

I guess I just wasn't searching by the right criteria.

Answer (score 1):

I am too late but here is what I did

```py
from django.db.models import DateTimeField, ExpressionWrapper, F

notes = Note.objects.annotate(my_dt=ExpressionWrapper(F('note_date') + F('note_time'), output_field=DateTimeField()))
```

Now we have added a new field my_dt of datetime type and can add a filter further to do operations

Comment: Thanks, xeon. Sounds like a nice new feature. Do you know when it became available?

Comment: No Idea I had similar issues few days ago. I am using it on Django 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

Here is another Approach which is more authentic

```
from django.db.models import Value, DateTimeField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast, Concat

notes = Note.objects.annotate(my_dt=Cast(
        Concat('note_date', Value(" "), 'note_time', output_field=DateTimeField()),
        output_field=DateTimeField()
    ).filter(my_dt__lte=datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution following others.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    from django.db import models
    datetime_wrapper = models.ExpressionWrapper(models.F('note_date') + models.F('note_time'), output_field=models.DateTimeField())
    return Note.objects.annotate(
        note_datetime=datetime_wrapper
    ).filter(note_datetime__gt=timezone.now()).order_by('note_datetime')
```