# Check remaning time to start a event is less then 24

Tags: python, django

In django I want to check how much time remaining to start a event , I know about this thing

```
 time_threshold = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=24)
 event = Event.objects.get(seleteddate__lt=time_threshold)
```

but my problem is I have saved startdate and start time in 2 diff variables like this

```
class Event(models.Model):
    seleteddate = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    startTime = models.TimeField()
```

**P.S** I cant make it a datetime field due to other use cases. So How I can check on basis of both that how much time it remaning to start an event.

Comment: So you want all the events which has difference of 24 hours or less betwenn `startTime` field and `seleteddate` field correct ?

Comment: @kashyapkn want to check how much time left to start this event from current time

Comment: This might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161042/filter-combined-date-and-time-in-django

Comment: @ThePjot  how I can get in Q that if event will start after 24 hours. I think we cant

Comment: What other use case(s) do you have preventing you from combing the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best approach, but this should work

```
 from datetime import datetime, date

 objs = Event.objects.all()

 for obj in objs:  
     date_obj = obj.seleteddate
     time_obj = obj.startTime
     # This would give us the datetime obj for that record
     datetime_obj = datetime.combine(date_obj, time_obj)

     # Subract the current datetime and datetime of the record to get no. of hours remaining
     hours_diff = (datetime.now()-datetime_obj).seconds//3600
     if hours_diff <= 24:
         # Logic to proceed
```

---